# Google GeoChart not working with Malaysia Map

Tags: google-visualization

Im trying to display some figures using GeoChart for Malaysia Map, its working fine, if display it in world map. But when drill into Malaysia Map, GeoChart can't display the value for the state.

Did I miss out something?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

  function drawMarkersMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Data'],
    ['Kedah', 5],
  ]);

  var options = {
    region: 'MY',
    displayMode: 'regions',
    resolution: 'provinces',
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar enough with the names of the provinces of Malaysia to know exactly how Google would render them, but I was able to color the provinces of Malaysia with the following code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'State');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Data');
  data.addRows([
    [{v:'MY-14', f:' Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur'}, 42],
    [{v:'MY-15', f:' Wilayah Persekutuan Labuan'}, 57],
    [{v:'MY-16', f:' Wilayah Persekutuan Putrajaya'}, 38],
    [{v:'MY-01', f:' Johor'}, 82],
    [{v:'MY-02', f:' Kedah'}, 46],
    [{v:'MY-03', f:' Kelantan'}, 51],
    [{v:'MY-04', f:' Melaka'}, 72],
    [{v:'MY-05', f:' Negeri Sembilan'}, 16],
    [{v:'MY-06', f:' Pahang'}, 2],
    [{v:'MY-08', f:' Perak'}, 87],
    [{v:'MY-09', f:' Perlis'}, 29],
    [{v:'MY-07', f:' Pulau Pinang'}, 49],
    [{v:'MY-12', f:' Sabah'}, 26],
    [{v:'MY-13', f:' Sarawak'}, 94],
    [{v:'MY-10', f:' Selangor'}, 35],
    [{v:'MY-11', f:' Terengganu'}, 79],
  ]);

  var options = {
    region: 'MY',
    displayMode: 'regions',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
  };


  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
    document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Whenever using Google GeoCharts on a province level, I like to use the [ISO-3166 alpha-2 province codes for that country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2%3aMY) since they will always work, and then I use the `{value: 'ISO 3166 alpha-2 code', format: 'human readable province name'}` trick to get it to display properly.